# Unknown Local Rsyncd Interruptions Error (104)

Tags: iptables, rsync

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 running UFW.

**Problem**:
No matter, whether I use rsync or rsyncd to backup my home folder, with the command below.  I always get `rsync error (104)`:

```
cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -5 rsync -avxP --delete --timeout=180 --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log --exclude 'snap'  --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" root@127.0.0.1::home /path/to/external/backup/folder
```

nmap confirrms that the rsync port is open:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
873/tcp open  rsync
```

When I check my rsync log, I see:

```
2022/08/09 08:43:44 [2610980] rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(145
8) [receiver=3.1.3]
2022/08/09 08:44:00 [2622644] name lookup failed for 192.168.0.11: Name or service
not known
2022/08/09 08:44:00 [2622644] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.0.11)
2022/08/09 08:44:05 [2622644] rsync on home/ from UNKNOWN (192.168.0.11)
```

I thought the problem might be with dnsmasq, which I run for local web development, so I added  `listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.0.11`  in my `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

no luck, same error.

**Update**
I successfully streamlined / synchronized my UFW / Webmin firewall rules as to eliminate any outdated entries.  But I still get the same error.  At this point.. I have no idea what the possible cause could be..

any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I use the same command to pull backups from my vps, therefore, I of course, use the `--timeout=""` option, so that wrapper script knows when to re-connect.

In my current situation, the timeout was getting triggered my while writing large files to an external hd drive (nowhere near as fast as my ssd drive).

Increasing the timeout to an hour `--timeout="3600"` (and/or removing it) got the above command working as intended.. (This problem has no relation to dnsmasq)